# How to design a dynamic programming algorithm that finds the longest common subsequence between two sequences?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

To illustrate the problem let's say that we have the sequence X and sequence Y and we want to find the longest common subsequence Z.

X : ACGTTGTA

Y: ACCCCTTTTA

We can deduce quickly that Z will be ACTTTA. We take the letters that are common to each sequence.

I'm fairly new to dynamic programming. My understanding is that we use previous solutions to find new ones.

I don't know what steps to follow to make a programming table.

This is what I've tried.

```
X             Y            Z
A             A            A
AC            AC           AC
ACC            ACG           AC
ACCC            ACGT           AC
ACCCC            ACGTT           AC
ACCCCT            ACGTTG           ACT
ACCCCTT            ACGTTGT           ACTT
ACCCCTTT            ACGTTGTA           ACTTT
ACCCCTTTT            ACGTTGTA           ACTTT
ACCCCTTTTA            ACGTTGTA           ACTTTA
```

Comment: If `dp[i][j]` is the LCS of the first `i` characters in `X` and the first `j` characters of `Y`, how would you compute the answer using values in `dp`? Hint: Compare the last characters of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Wikipedia has the full solution if that's what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Solution_for_two_sequences

Comment: How is a dynamic programming function defined in general? Is there a wikipedia article that explain this?

Comment: I'm assuming that by "dynamic programming function" you're referring to the recursive function which we compute to find the solution. There's no general method to determine what your DP function should be. You need to find a DP function such that the total number of states that you need to compute is small enough, and the transitions can be done quickly. Coming up with such a function just takes practice.

Comment: This might help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence-dp-4/